# Integrating w.r.t. multiple measures

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $\mu_1,\mu_2$ be measures in $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ and let $\mu=a.\mu_1+b.\mu_2$, for $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$. If $f$ is integrable, is it true that

$$\int_\Omega f d\mu=a\int_{\Omega}fd\mu_1+b\int_\Omega f d\mu_2\:\: ?$$

My attempt

Firstly, note that for a nonnegative simple function $\phi=\sum_{i=1}^N c_i\chi(E_i)$ we have
$$
\begin{split}
\int \phi d\mu &=\sum_ic_i(a\mu_1+b\mu_2)(E_i)\\
&=\sum_ic_i a\mu_1(E_i)+c_ib\mu_2(E_i)\\
&=a\int \phi d\mu_1+b\int \phi d\mu_2.
\end{split}
$$
It means that
 $$\bigg\{\int\phi d\mu:0\leq\phi\leq f,\phi \ \text{simple}\bigg\}=a\bigg\{\int\phi d\mu_1:0\leq\phi\leq f,\phi \ \text{simple}\bigg\}+b\bigg\{\int\phi d\mu_2:0\leq\phi\leq f,\phi \ \text{simple}\bigg\}
$$
So for a nonnegative measurable function $g$ we have (by applying the supremum)
$$
\int g d\mu=a\int g d\mu_1+b\int g d\mu_2.
$$
Now, write $f=f^+-f^-$, and since $f^+$ and $f^-$ are nonnegative the result follows.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Yes, I don't see anything wrong with it.